# Insert a formatted date inside an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS for beginners and I want to insert the Date() function with the format 'MMM d, y' inside the object.date  property?

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Info = {
    author: "",
    rating: 5,
    comment: ""
  };
  $scope.x = Date();
  $scope.today = $filter('date')($scope.x)]; $scope.Info.date = $scope.today;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest moment.js library

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, but here is how you handle dates in Angularjs. I noticed someone mentioned moment.js which is a solid library but may be a little more than what you need. Make sure to inject `$filter` into your controller as well.

Try this:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.Info = {
    author: "",
    rating: 5,
    comment: ""
  };

  $scope.today = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MMM d, y'); 
  $scope.Info.date = $scope.today;
});
</script>
```

Here is a super simplified version with less code.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.Info = {
    author: "",
    rating: 5,
    comment: "",
    date: $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MMM d, y')
  };
});
</script>
```